# How to count only the words that I want?

Tags: python

I want to count only **words** of a dictionary.
For example :
There is a text :
Children can bye (paid) by credit card.
I want to count just paid.
But my code counts (paid).

```
import re, sys
d = {}
m = "children can bye (paid) by credit card."
n = m.split()
for i in n:
            d[i] = 0
    for j in n:
            d[j] = d[j] + 1
```

Is there any advice ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You mean you want to get rid of the parentheses around the word (and presumably other punctuation)?

Comment: Unrelated, but do you mean "children can *buy* by credit card."?

Comment: Post some sample text and the expected output

Comment: what is your dictionary? and also the sentence don't make sense.

Comment: "How to count only the words that I want?" is a really vague question, haha

Comment: for examlpe there is a text :  children can buy (pay) by credit card.                                                                  output : children : 1, can : 1, buy : 1, (pay) : 1, by : 1, creditcard : 1           - I want to count just pay  no (pay)   . understand ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string with the following regex to split by nonword chars:

```
import re
n = re.split('\W+', m)
```

You can check the syntax [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: isn't that regex the same as `str.split()`?

Comment: @2er0 No. str.split() gives you `(paid)` instead of `paid`

Comment: `split()` splits on whitespace; the regexp splits on runs of "non-word" characters (including whitespace, but not **just** whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the punctuation from your individual tokens. Assuming you want to remove *all* the punctuation, take a look at the [`string`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-constants) module. Then (for example), you can go through each token and remove the punctuation. You can do this with one list comprehension:

```
words = [''.join(ch for ch in token if ch not in string.punctuation) 
         for token in m.split()]
```

All this code does is run through each character (`ch`) in each token (the results of `m.split()`). It allows all characters except it'll strip out any characters in `string.punctuation`. Of course if you want a different set of characters (say, maybe you want to allow apostrophes), you can just define that set of characters and use that instead.